# Error No provider for NgZone

Tags: angular, maps, angular-google-maps, angularjs-injector, ngzone

I have an application that uses Angular Google Maps to show a location. At the beginning I was able to show the map, but since a while (probably I have modified something) I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[NgZone]: 
StaticInjectorError[NgZone]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for NgZone!
at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10585)
at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:11806)
at resolveDep (core.js:12302)
at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10585)
at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:11806)
at resolveDep (core.js:12302)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
at eval (zone.js:873)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
at <anonymous>
```

My code is:
app.module.ts:

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

imports AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey:'...'})
```

mycomponent.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
        <agm-info-window>
            <div>
                my text
            </div>
        </agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can follow the stack and check where the error takes place. Currently you're the only person who can do that. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem - a plunk, stackblitz, etc.

Comment: Hi, I am interested in this. Did you find any way to fix the issue ?

Comment: `zone`'s included in most apps in `polyfills.ts`. `polyfills.ts` is included by `angular.json`. Have you modified either of these files?

Comment: has anyone solved this yet?  I'm encountering the exact same error.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide `NgZone` manually:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        // ...
        { provide: NgZone, useFactory: () => new NgZone({}) }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add peerDependencies with all the libraries you are using using.

Also check by removing each Module from your imports to see which one is causing the issue.
This **[`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614615/angular-6-the-result-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression)** should help.