# use modified angular cdk module in other project locally

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I have forked, cloned and modified the angular material repository to suit my needs. Code in the dev-app runs fine.

Now I want to use this module, more precisely the `DragDropmodule` of `@angular/cdk`, in another angular app I am working on.

I therefore ran `gulp cdk:build-release` and obtained the `dist/releases/cdk` folder containing built modules.

**How do I use this compiled module's `DragDropModule` in my other project now?** I tried `npm link`. This works to some extent as I can import the module now by

`import { DragDropModule } from 'material2c/dist/releases/cdk/drag-drop';`

However, trying `ng serve` gives a bunch of errors

`ERROR in C:/Users/admin/Documents/material2/dist/releases/cdk/esm5/drag-drop.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi' in 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\material2\dist\releases\cdk\esm5'
ERROR in C:/Users/admin/Documents/material2/dist/releases/cdk/esm5/drag-drop.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/coercion' in 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\material2\dist\releases\cdk\esm5'
ERROR in C:/Users/admin/Documents/material2/dist/releases/cdk/esm5/drag-drop.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/platform' in 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\material2\dist\releases\cdk\esm5'
ERROR in C:/Users/admin/Documents/material2/dist/releases/cdk/esm5/drag-drop.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling' in 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\material2\dist\releases\cdk\esm5'`

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: coud you create a github/stackblitz example for the same ? It will hepl us know where exactly the issue is coming from. Reading the consolable logs is not giving a full picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import should remain the same if the project is correctly linked. Eg:

`import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk'`

This is because `npm link` creates a link from the linked project to `./node_modules/@angular/cdk` in the target project.

If you need to share the module around, you may be interested in running `npm pack` in the dist directory of the module, which should output a tarball that you can then npm install to your project and easily share with other people.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the answer. I had no luck linking it with npm/yarn directly. When doing `npm pack`, putting the tgz to the product folder and including it as a devDependency, it worked. Do you know why?

Comment: Try running `npm link ../../path/to/dist/dir` in the project directory you're trying to link into

Comment: thanks, the trick was to allow preserving symlinks in the angular.json file. Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123513/537865